# How to get file bytes in a given range?

Tags: java, file, arrays

How to get file bytes in a given range? File might be very big, so keeping all the bytes in memory is not good idea. Can I just read the file byte by byte? Is reading like that normal?

Comment: Have a look at `RandomAccessFile` .

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, binary

Answer (score 5):

Open the file using a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), seek to the beginning offset, define the buffer length and read the buffer fully. The [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement takes care of closing the `RandomAccessFile`.

```
public static byte[] readByteRange(String sourceFilePath, long startingOffset, int length) throws IOException
{
    try (RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(sourceFilePath, "r"))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        randomAccessFile.seek(startingOffset);
        randomAccessFile.readFully(buffer);

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Berger, you can use **RandomAccessFile** in java. You can use something like below code to read the file randomly.

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("FilePath","r");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
f.read(buffer, 10, 100);
```

Below is the documentation of read() method from java-doc-

```
/**
 * Reads up to <code>len</code> bytes of data from this file into an
 * array of bytes. This method blocks until at least one byte of input
 * is available.
 * <p>
 * Although <code>RandomAccessFile</code> is not a subclass of
 * <code>InputStream</code>, this method behaves in exactly the
 * same way as the {@link InputStream#read(byte[], int, int)} method of
 * <code>InputStream</code>.
 *
 * @param      b     the buffer into which the data is read.
 * @param      off   the start offset in array <code>b</code>
 *                   at which the data is written.
 * @param      len   the maximum number of bytes read.
 * @return     the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
 *             <code>-1</code> if there is no more data because the end of
 *             the file has been reached.
 * @exception  IOException If the first byte cannot be read for any reason
 * other than end of file, or if the random access file has been closed, or if
 * some other I/O error occurs.
 * @exception  NullPointerException If <code>b</code> is <code>null</code>.
 * @exception  IndexOutOfBoundsException If <code>off</code> is negative,
 * <code>len</code> is negative, or <code>len</code> is greater than
 * <code>b.length - off</code>
 */
public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    return readBytes(b, off, len);
}
```

Comment: This looks wrong : the documentation states that you may not get exactly the number of bytes you ask for. So... you should make your code loop until this is the case.

Comment: You can look at the source code for DataInputStream#readFully, which does that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking it is rarely a good idea to load an entire file into memory unless you know that it will always be small enough to fit into your memory and you won't load several files in parallel otherwise you may face `OOME`.

If you want to read a file, you can indeed read byte by byte thanks to the method [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) but in practice it is used in very specific use cases where you need to read few bytes as it is not an optimized way to read an entire file.

The common code in this case is:

```
int data;
while ((data = input.read()) != -1) {
    // Do something with data
}
```

If you want to read your file faster you should use the method [read(byte[] b)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])), it allows to reuse an array of bytes previously created by the caller code and read a range of bytes like what you want to do.

The common code in this case is:

```
int length;
byte[] data = new byte[someSizeHere];
while ((length = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    // Do something with the bytes in data between index 0 and length - 1
}
```

If you want to skip some bytes before starting to read your range of bytes, you can indeed use `RandomAccessFile` and its method [seek(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long))